# Locking Out Admin After Migration - Magento

Tags: magento, admin

So I've gotten myself into a bit of a pickle and need assistance from StackOverflow Gods.

We're trying to transfer a Magento site from one server (Godaddy) to another (Private Virtual Server) for the purpose of becoming a test site.

I'm not familiar with Magento (my first mistake) but I researched migration, and I ran across an article that said all you need to transfer is the database, theme files, catalog files and skin files.

So that's just what we did. We setup a fresh install, added the files and the site (http://boulderfootandankle.com/apv-test/) looks like it's got some formatting errors. We figured we could fix those after adding the database.

As soon as we connected the database through the local.xml file, the theme changed to a generic one (I imagine a fallback) and we were locked out of the admin.

I tried a number of the solutions offered for this very problem, which included:

1. Clearing the var/cache and var/session folders.
2. Altering the core config data values for the unsecure and secure web base urls.
3. Deleting the unsecure and secure web base urls and cookie values form the database.
4. Changing the sessions save CDATA from "files" to "db"
5. Changing the install date to the original
6. Altering the varien file

...and nothing seems to work.

At this point, I'm just wondering if doing a fresh transfer of the site from one server to another, instead of transferring specific files into a fresh install, would work

Comment: Are you still having the site running on Godaddy? If yes ,Are you using any other domain on new server? DSN switch done?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the same encryption key as the previous installation? The encryption key is set in the local.xml file and needs to be the same on both extensions. When you did a fresh install it would have given you a new encryption key and this could be why you are unable to login.

Answer (score 0):

just my quick list for transferring sites...
1. run files backup and mysql dump (from source)
2. Copy local.xml (from Target)
3. Restore backup and mysql dump (to Target)
4. Restore local.xml(from step 2 to Target)
5. Correct base_url (in Target)

The only time I have ever had a problem with this is when I run things locally for dev in that case there is varien specific check that monks with admin login(but, sounds like you know this).
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/magento-1-9-can-t-login-to-admin-panel

I am on 1.14 and the posters suggestion essentially is the same fix I found. Of course the responder is totally correct on the horror of this solution but, since this is a test site as long as you leave yourself the right notes you should be able to undo this when you move to production.